# Detecting when role is given to a member with my bot discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to detect when a user is given a certain role on a server.

My code is:

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes

const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const settings = require('./config.json');

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  partials: [Partials.Channel],
});

client.on('ready', () => {
   console.log("- Bot logged in -");
});
client.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    console.log("updated")
    const oldRoles = oldMember.roles.cache,
          newRoles = newMember.roles.cache;

    // Has Role?
    const oldHas = oldRoles.has('1093515437792305222'),
          newHas = newRoles.has('1093515437792305222');

    // Check if removed or added
    if (!oldHas && newHas) {
        console.log("got role")

    }
});
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  console.log("got message")
  if (message.content.includes('changeNick')) {
    message.member.setNickname(message.content.replace('changeNick ', ''));
}
});

client.login(settings.token);
```

Everything works, apart from the role update. I have tried adding intentions, but maybe didn't set the right ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `guildMemberUpdate` event will need the `Guilds`, `GuildMembers` and `GuildPresences` intents to fire:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  partials: [Partials.Channel],
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a list of these intents anywhere?

Comment: @Fxkitt https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents here